# Looking for Delphi 7 for 64-bit windows 7 . free download?

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking to install Delphi 7 for free on my 64-bit windows 7, it urgent I need it for work.

Comment: Downvoters, this may ot be a piracy request. I do remember, long, long, looooong, ago that there was a free version of Delphi 7. It was even given away on some magazine covers (probably in the hope of upgrade sales) and could probably be found by soem intensive Googling.. However, it was 32 bit and I would not expect there to be a free a 64-bit version. @Sana, you say that you need it for work - your employer should provide the necessary tools (and amuch more recent version). If not, then Steve's answer should help - Lazarus in an excellent product.

Comment: "I need it for work" - then your company should provide the tools which you need in order to to work. It is not your responsibility to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a [free trial](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/start-for-free) to evaluate but would need to purchase later - alternatively you could use the Open Source [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/) IDE and libraries.

Lazarus:

> Lazarus is a Delphi compatible cross-platform IDE for Rapid
>   Application Development. It has variety of components ready for use
>   and a graphical form designer to easily create complex graphical user
>   interfaces.

Comment: I want Delphi 7 even for free trial but it is said in embarcadero that the download has ended in 31 december 2015

Comment: I googled for "delphi 7 last free version" and found a few sources, but 32 bit only. You will not find a free 64 bit version. Emarcadero does sell cheap "personal" verssoins for about $200, but they are 32 bit only & have no database functionality. They will not give away or even sell cheaply a 64 bit version. Expect toppay about $1k

Comment: @Mawg - Sounds like Lazarus would be a much better bet!

Comment: I totally agree - in general. However, the OP does not say why he wants D7, and not the current XE10 or any other version. I would guess that he has been given an existing D7 project - and does not realize that he can import it into  XE10. I would, even with an existing D7 project, go with Lazarus. Unless there is some compelling reason - could there be, for instance, a D7 VCL component which can't be used with Lazarus? @Sana, could you give us more info?